# How is it possible to make this app working with mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, html5-canvas, android-canvas, mobile-browser

I am working on an app for drawing using HTML 5 Canvas the problem that it's working well on computer browser like this picture
http://s28.postimg.org/z0ytnva98/problem.jpg

I want to make it working on mobile browser (never mind working on both, mobile browser is what I want).
the problem in my code concerning the Java Script events.
I change it to

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart' , engage);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', putpoint);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend' , disengage);
```

but didn't work i also tried

```
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart' , engage);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', putpoint);
canvas.addEventListener('touchleave' , disengage);
```

also didn't work.
when I leave it to as it was like this

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown' , engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putpoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup' , disengage);
```

it make just a point like this picture
http://s14.postimg.org/tadk87jpt/Screenshot_2015_02_15_20_16_32.png

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drawing app</title>
<body style="overflow: hidden">
<canvas id="canvas" style="width:100% ; height:100%">
    Your browser does not support canvas element.
</canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        radius = 20,
        dragging = false;

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    context.lineWidth = radius*2;
    var putpoint = function(e){
        if(dragging){
            context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
            context.stroke();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
            context.fill();
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        }
    };

    var engage = function(e){
        dragging = true;
        putpoint(e);
        };

    var disengage = function(){
        dragging = false;
        context.beginPath();
        };

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown' , engage);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putpoint);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup' , disengage);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of the different [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events) from the MDN seems to be building a demo to do just what you're trying to do. Check out what they do in their solution.